# get specific data using php in nested array in json

Tags: php, json, curl

So they have this JSON and i need specific items to get e.g. promotions:

```
{
    "currency": "USD",
    "code": 200,
    "sales_list": [
                    {
                        "date": "2012-05-21",
                        "country": "JP",
                         units:{
                               app: {
                                             downloads: 10,
                                             updates: 1,
                               },
                               iap: {
                                             sales: 3,
                                             refunds: 5,
                                             promotions:1
                               },
                         },
                         revenue: {
                                 app: {
                                             downloads “100.98”,
                                             refunds: “-10.00”,
                                             promotions: “1.00”
                                 },
                                 iap: {
                                             sales: “30.00”,
                                             refunds: “-1.00”,
                                 },
                                 ad: "1000.00"
                             },
              }],
“iap_sales”:[
              {
                  "date": "2012-05-21",
                  "country": "JP",
                  “iap”:  “com.iap1”,
                   units:{
                          sales: 3,
                          refunds: 5,
                   },
                   revenue: {
                             sales: "30.09",
                             refunds: "1.21",
                   },
               }],
    "page_index": 1,
}
```

How do i get the to the promotions?

I tried to use this:

```
    $json_data = connect(t_url);

    $data = json_decode($json_data);

    return $data->sales_list[0]->units[0]->app[0]->promotions;
```

but is it even effective/ efficient?

Also im having a hard time getting data from appannie. i always get authorization problem or bad request. If bad request it means im in though right?

I use the terminal to test curl and my url like:

```
curl --basic --user email : password "http:/www.appannie.com/v1/accounts/acntnum/..."
```

they suggested this since they have authentication. There are time i get bad request but i think im in unlike `unauthorized access` error.

They also suggest other forms like the authethication should be basic+base 64 of ur eadd and password. But I don't know where to use it.

Any suggestions to convert this into php curl request?

Comment: Load the whole thing as an array... it will make your life easier: `json_decode($json, true)` and access with: `$data['sales_list][0]['inits']['app']['promotions']`

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json);` will give you an object that contains the data, and also give you a bit more flexibility then the multi-dim array.